# ssrs : parameter combined with a lookup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, report

I got the following issue

I'm running the stored procedure below. it has a parameter,**`@choix_de_l_adresse`**, as an input

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Adresse1 
@choix_de_l_adresse VARCHAR(38)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT John_Jack.Siren,
            CASE 
                WHEN John_Jack.Adresse1_Eco IS NULL THEN ''
                WHEN John_Jack.Adresse1_Post IS NULL THEN ''
                WHEN (John_Jack.Adresse1_Eco IS NOT NULL 
                OR John_Jack.Adresse1_Post IS NOT NULL)
                AND @choix_de_l_adresse = 'Adresse Postale' THEN Adresse1_Post
                ELSE Adresse1_Eco
            END AS adresse1
    FROM John_Jack
END
```

Stored procedure is running fine when I'm using the management studio console.

I've setup the parameter in ssrs

However, when setting it up the stored procedure as a dataset , I'm running into a few problems:

1) This window is popping out

[image]

I'm trying to add **[@choix_de_l_adresse@]** or **@choix_de_l_adresse** inside of the parameter value but it is giving me this

[image]

2) I'm trying to bruteforce the parameters as I've seen in the internet but to no avail

[image]

Last , but not least I'm doing a `lookup` combining the parameter like below

```
=Lookup(Fields!Siren.Value,Fields!Siren.Value,Parameters!adresse1.Value,"adresse1")
```

However it is giving me the lethal bullet `Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current datascope [...]`

Do you have any idea on the why?

**Update** : Please find a screen capture of my dataset query below

[image]

Comment: Did you manually create the prameter?

Comment: Hi @WesPalmer, on the bruteforce part , yes. Otherwise I've created `choix_de_l_adresse` as a parameter, manually

Comment: Have you tried hooking up the data source first. When I have hooked the stored procedure up as the datasource it has created the parameter for me and I just needed to give it a datasource that loaded the parameter.

Comment: What do you mean hooking up the datasource first, @WesPalmer?

Comment: Sorry I meant Dataset. When I use the Stored Procedure as my Data Source SSRS is smart enough to create the parameter for you then you get to choose how to load it with data.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the `Query` tab of your Dataset properties?

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman, not at work tonight (I'm in France). I will provide a screenshot tomorrow.

Comment: When going into the Query Designer I have ALWAYS been required to either specify parameter values or choose the checkbox `Pass Null Value` for each parameter, and if I FORGET to do this, I always see the error _"Could not update a list of fields for the query"_

Comment: Hi @DavidTansey, alas when I check the `pass null value` parameter, I have the same `'Could not update a list of fields [...]'` ...

Any other ideas are welcomed ... :)

Comment: Everyone, I was able to deal with my issue by having a workaround. However, I would like to fix my issue and be able to use a stored procedure. It would be handy , in the near future

Comment: I will put my solution on Friday. I'm on training with the client , tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find out how to resolve my issue. However, I found a decent workaround.

Instead of creating a stored procedure , I put part of my code into `ssrs`

The code is now like this

```
DECLARE @choix_de_l_adresse VARCHAR(38)
    SELECT John_Jack.Siren,
            CASE 
                WHEN John_Jack.Adresse1_Eco IS NULL THEN ''
                WHEN John_Jack.Adresse1_Post IS NULL THEN ''
                WHEN (John_Jack.Adresse1_Eco IS NOT NULL 
                OR John_Jack.Adresse1_Post IS NOT NULL)
                AND @choix_de_l_adresse = 'Adresse Postale' THEN Adresse1_Post
                ELSE Adresse1_Eco
            END AS adresse1
    FROM John_Jack
```

Then set the proper dataset (see below)

[image]

And select the proper parameter (see below)

[image]

Once done , everything is working a treat